# Title in box in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

1)How to put the title on the titlepage in Beamer to a block of a desired color? Similarly like in themes Warsaw, Berlin...
2)How to control space between author and date? `\vspace` seems does not work.

1) I use this

```
\title[TITLE]{TITLE\\[1em]
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{logo}\\[1em]}
\subtitle{\textbf{Subtitle}}
```

But I want teh box only around TITLE . How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can redefine the `title page` template and introduce the necessary modifications for the layout; this redefinition is needed since both the title and the subtitle are, by deafult, inside the same `beamercolorbox` so simply redefining the `title` beamer color would produce a box around both title and subtitle (which is not wanted here):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{TITLE}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{cat}}
\subtitle{\textbf{Subtitle}}
\author{Author}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=orange,fg=white}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white,fg=structure}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip-1em\par % change here
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that now there's no need to use `\title[TITLE]{TITLE\includegraphics{...}}` but now you can simply use `\title{TITLE}` and \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[]{}}`. Of course, feel free to make the necessary adjutments according to your particular needs (yo can play with the lengths in the \vskip commands to adjust vertical spacing).

As requested in a comment, to have a colored box around only the subtitle, the necessary modifications are the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{TITLE}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{cat}}
\subtitle{\textbf{Subtitle}}
\author{Author}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
      \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=orange,fg=white}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip-1em\par % change here
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a new request, here's the code to change at will the width of the box used for the subtitle; change the length used for `\subtitwd` (initially set to `4cm`) according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength\subtitwd
\setlength\subtitwd{4cm}% change the width here

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
      \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=orange,fg=white}
      \vbox{%
         \hfill\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\subtitwd,sep=8pt,center]{title}
            {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}\hfill\null%
      }%
      \fi%     
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip-1em\par % change here
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\title{TITLE}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{cat}}
\subtitle{\textbf{Subtitle}}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified the question above.

Comment: @Laura Ah, OK. Give me some minutes ;-)

Comment: By the way. I'm glad you put the sample here. At least I can show you which line I still have in my mind. So I would like to get rid of the symbols situated on the bottom on the right side in your example above.

Comment: @Laura but those are the navigation symbols! Simply use `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}`. By the way, I updated my answer with a solution to the original problems.

Comment: Great, it was really navigation symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the modification. I didn't expect it could be so complicated to put box around the name of title. I would need to change everything, so better I will leave it without box:-) Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: @Laura I updated my answer with the necessary modifications.

Comment: @Gonzola: Could the box around subtitle be shorter? The name of my subtitle is quite short and it looks strange.

Comment: @Laura Answer updated with the necessary code.