# Putting a subtitle on a Beamer document

Tags: beamer, positioning, titles

I want to put the subtitle "Tesis sometida para obtar por al grado de Maestría Académica en Matemática" below and to not be colored in orange. Like for example, just above my name.

[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
\title[Representaciones de grupos de simetría]%

{\textbf{Las representaciones metapléctica y de espín\\
de ciertos grupos de simetría:\\
un estudio comparativo}}
 
\subtitle[Tesis]{\footnotesize {\emph{Tesis sometida para obtar por al grado de Maestría Académica en Matemática}}}

\author[Adrián J. Naranjo A.]{Adrián José Naranjo Alvarado}

\institute[]{\small Escuela de Matemática,
                    Universidad de Costa Rica}

\date{10 de septiembre del 2021}
```

Any help would me greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not know the theme etc., and I am only guessing the values, the solution should be a bit modified. It is based on the answer to [Title in box in Beamer presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68655/title-in-box-in-beamer-presentation)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
      \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white!15!orange,fg=structure}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true,]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    
    \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white,fg=structure}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip-1em\par % change here
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title[Representaciones de grupos de simetría]%
{\textbf{Las representaciones metapléctica y de espín\\
de ciertos grupos de simetría:\\
un estudio comparativo}}
 
\subtitle[Tesis]{\footnotesize {\emph{Tesis sometida para obtar por al grado de Maestría Académica en Matemática}}}

\author[Adrián J. Naranjo A.]{Adrián José Naranjo Alvarado}

\institute[]{\small Escuela de Matemática,
                    Universidad de Costa Rica}

\date{10 de septiembre del 2021}



\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to move things within the title page around, you're better off (re)defining your own `title page` template. I grabbed the default associated with the `Madrid` theme (you may be using a different theme/colour), commented out the location of the `subtitle` components and added them into the `author` "block". You can adjust the placement by changing the `\vskip`s within the new template.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}% Title font
\title[Representaciones de grupos de simetría]%
  {Las representaciones metapléctica y de espín\\
    de ciertos grupos de simetría:\\
    un estudio comparativo}

\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\footnotesize,shape=\itshape,series=\mdseries}% Subtitle font
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=black}% Subtitle foreground colour
\subtitle[Tesis]{Tesis sometida para obtar por al grado de Maestría Académica en Matemática}

\author[Adrián J. Naranjo A.]{Adrián José Naranjo Alvarado}

\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}% Institute font
\institute[]{Escuela de Matemática, Universidad de Costa Rica}

\date{10 de septiembre del 2021} 

% (Re)define title page template
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}%
      \inserttitle
      %\par
      %\ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else
      %  \vskip 0.25em
      %  {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}%
      %   \usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}%
      %   \insertsubtitle
      %   \par}
      %\fi
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip 1em
    \par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{author}
      {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}%
       \usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}%
       \insertsubtitle
       \par}
      \vskip 1em
      \usebeamerfont{author}%
      \insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}%
      \insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}%
      \insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip 0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}%
     \inserttitlegraphic
     \par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful :D.