# Add image to title slide of presentation

Tags: beamer

I use beamer with the warsaw style to create presentation. I would like to insert an image in the title slide as part of customization. I would like to add a to my title slide such that the author, institution, date are on the right side and the image is on the left side. I attached a sample image.[image]

Comment: Just for my understanding: Did you check beamers manual, e.g. at https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf ? // E.g. did you try on p. 94 "\inserttitlegraphic inserts the title graphic into a template."?

Comment: See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21356/adding-custom-image-in-title-slide?rq=1 or herer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68655/title-in-box-in-beamer-presentation?rq=1 from the "Related" column to the right.